# Cookie file not being written to php curl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I recently installed a LAMP stack on an Ubuntu server. I am having problems with my *curl* script. I have the following code:

```
function curl_request($page, $postvalues = false) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/var/www/html/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/var/www/html/cookie.txt");

    if (isset($postvalues) && $postvalues != false) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvalues);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "CURL ERROR<BR />" . curl_error($ch) . "<br /><br /><br />";
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Whenever I run this script, it never edits the `/var/www/html/cookie.txt` file. 
The file is always blank. I've changed the permissions and done all of that, changed the file name, tried using relative path, etc. Why is the file not being edited?

Comment: Changed permissions to what? Also, what do your error_logs say?

Comment: I have tried all permissions, first it was 0644, i changed it to 0755 and then even changed it 0777, i checked with PHP and the is_writable() function returns true so the file has permission to be written to but its just not working.